# Informatica Conversion to Hql for reg_match and reg_extract

Tags: hql, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I want to convert this expression for a column to hql.

iiF(ISNULL(NAME),'#',iif(reg_match(UPPER(NAME),'.*,\s*CLASS.*'),REG_EXTRACT(NAME,'(.*),\s*(Class\s*U.*)$','I'),NAME)

As I tried to go through Informatica Documentation for reg_match and reg_extract but was not sure how it is being applied here.

Do help me understand how is this working and what will be its conversion in hql

Comment: Check my answer on related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75641931/2834065.

Comment: Hi @Maciejg, I went through the documentation but I'm still not sure how its being used here and what will be its sql conversion.