# REG_EXTRACT doesnt work in IICS Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud, iics, iics-di

I have a value (URL)

```
https://test.com/insight/api/view?entity_type=event&entity_id=6557856
```

and when I am trying to apply this function:

```
REG_EXTRACT (value, 'entity_id=(\d+)',1)
```

i am getting NULL instead of a proper value. https://regex101.com/ validates the pattern and it seems to be correct.

Comment: Pls use this documentation. Infa may not support all patterns. https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-4-0/transformation-language-reference/functions/reg_extract.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't enough to just match the pattern you want to extract; you have to match the **entire** string and then have **groupings** for the bits you want to extract.

Even though this question is for IICS, if we look closely [at the (poorly explained) example provided for Power Centre](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-4-0/transformation-language-reference/functions/reg_extract.html), we can see that the reg-ex they've provided matches the entire example string but breaks it down into 3 groups (the bracketed sections) and from those it takes the 2nd grouping:

```
REG_EXTRACT( Employee_Name, '(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)', 2)
```

| Employee_Name | Return Value |
| --- | --- |
| Stephen Graham Smith | Graham |
| Juan Carlos Fernando | Carlos |

Although I've not tested it, I'm fairly certain in the above that if someone came through with 4 names, (e.g. Stephen Graham Smith Johnstone), then their pattern wouldn't match either.

The way I'd approach your string in [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/) is first match everything and then narrow it down to get the grouping in place:

```
https://test.com/insight/api/view?entity_type=event&entity_id=6557856
```

- .* to match the entire URL
- &entity_id= to narrow down where the grouping will be
- (\d+) to create a group around the digits

Giving:

```
.*&entity_id=(\d+)
```

Obviously you might want to make it a bit stricter, but that should be enough to get you the match you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how REG_EXTRACT works. It is not similar to RegEx101. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75641931/2834065) - you first need to write a matcher that will cover whole string and then extract the required group.